# Extract time remip srcip msg status from my log file entry

Tags: powershell

I have txt file in which my VPN client connection information has written. I wanna note the following info and export them into csv. Information need to be written in exported csv **time** + **remip** + **srcip** + **msg** + **user** + **status**. through my code i am able to get  **time** and **remip**. appreciate if some one help me in this.

**LOG FILE**
{2022-07-17 17:08:12    Local7.Info 10.10.50.14 date=2022-07-17 time=17:08:12 devname="FortiGate-201F" devid="FG201FT920901378" logid="0101039424" type="event" subtype="vpn" level="information" vd="root" eventtime=1658059692736060755 tz="+0500" logdesc="SSL VPN tunnel up" action="tunnel-up" tunneltype="ssl-web" tunnelid=850652314 remip=10.10.50.182 user="abc" group="N/A" dst_host="N/A" reason="login successfully" msg="SSL tunnel established"

2022-07-17 17:08:13 Local7.Notice   10.10.50.14 date=2022-07-17 time=17:08:13 devname="FortiGate-201F" devid="FG201FT920901378" logid="0102043039" type="event" subtype="user" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1658059693829159815 tz="+0500" logdesc="Authentication logon" srcip="10.212.134.200" user="abc" authserver="N/A" action="auth-logon" status="logon" msg="User abc added to auth logon"

2022-07-17 17:09:04 Local7.Notice   10.10.50.14 date=2022-07-17 time=17:09:04 devname="FortiGate-201F" devid="FG201FT920901378" logid="0102043040" type="event" subtype="user" level="notice" vd="root" eventtime=1658059744761943019 tz="+0500" logdesc="Authentication logout" srcip="10.212.134.200" user="abc" authserver="N/A" action="auth-logout" status="logout" msg="User abc removed from auth logon"}

**This is my PowerShell code in which ragex command is used for getting the required info**

```
$input_path = 'C:\Users\sajjad\Documents\test\sil\*.txt'

$output_file = 'C:\Users\sajjad\Documents\test\sil\VpnLogInLogOff.csv'

$regex = '\b(time|remip|user|msg)\b=([^\s ]+)' #regular expression is providing time and remote ip. 

Select-String $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {

    $obj = New-Object pscustomobject
```

Comment: by mentioned log file using my code i am able to get this information in csv 


time          remip   user                  msg
17:08:12 10.10.50.182  "abc"                  "SSL (after space all words is missing)
17:08:13                   "abc"                 "User (after space all words is missing)
17:09:04                   "abc"                 "User (after space all words is missing)

Comment: yes you are right

here is my complete code

****$input_path = 'C:\Users\sajjad\Documents\test\sil\*.txt'
$output_file = 'C:\Users\sajjad\Documents\test\sil\VpnLogInLogOff.csv'
$regex = '\b(time|remip|user|msg)\b=([^\s ]+)'

Select-String $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = New-Object pscustomobject
    foreach ($match in $_.Matches) {
      Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName $match.Groups[1].Value -NotePropertyValue $match.Groups[2].Value
    }
    $obj
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $output_file
****

Comment: i will be very thank full to you if you help me out - Olaf i  do not know as much about coding but this task need to be done immediately for my office

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, except:

- the regex isn't sophisticated enough to capture *double-quoted* values.
- the code to turn the matches into `[pscustomobject]` instances is missing

```bash
# Improved regex to support capturing "..."-enclosed values.
$regex = '\b(time|remip|user|msg)=("[^"]*"|\S+)'

Select-String $input_path -AllMatches -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object {

    # Use an aux. ordered hashtable to capture the matches
    # as key-value pairs.
    $oht = [ordered] @{}
    foreach ($m in $_.Matches) {
      $oht[$m.Groups[1].Value] = $m.Groups[2].Value.Trim('"')
    }
    # Convert the aux. ordered hashtable to a custom object.
    # Note: In PowerShell 7.2+ this step is no longer needed.
    [pscustomobject] $oht

} # | Export-Csv ....  # pipe to Export-Csv as needed.
```